Need a way for upload content on my site from a form
I'm just getting into java and php and so I looked for something online and I helped myself with AI to create something that worked, so I apologize in advance if I don't understand something and if I post errors.
I'm creating a site for a car dealer (purely advertising,
you don't buy anything) and I need to create a form that the gentleman will fill out every month (obviously it is hidden on a page accessible with password) the form with the info of the cars with the various characteristics and this information then must go to create a POST on the site. (must come like pic.1)
I am ignorant about backend and frontend, but is this possible? (I guess so)

I tried to implement jotform and I was able to get something from it but it didn't appear like a written post, you could see the whole table behind it (see pic.2) and I didn't like it at all.
I tried with AI to create something,
and it works locally, but if I publish the site obviously the data doesn't remain, if I refresh the page everything is cleaned up and therefore in practice nothing was written on the site, but it was a local memory. I had to unlock (if I understood correctly...
) the html page to give permission to the server to write on the page but obviously I don't know how to do this from the host... I use register.it (horrible, but they forced me).

Help me please.
*result i want pic.1
*
*form example
*
*jotform result pic.2
*
this is my js code


// Contatore per generare ID univoci per il carousel
var carouselIdCounter = 0;

// Array per salvare le URL delle immagini caricate
var imageUrls = [];

// Carica i dati dal backend all'avvio della pagina
window.onload = function() {
    loadSavedCars();
};

// Funzione per caricare le auto salvate dal backend
function loadSavedCars() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cars')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(cars => {
            cars.forEach(car => {
                displayCar(car);
            });
        });
}

// Funzione per aggiungere l'immagine alla lista delle immagini
function addImageToList() {
    var imageInput = document.getElementById("image");
    var files = imageInput.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        // Crea un URL temporaneo per l'immagine e aggiungilo all'array
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        imageUrls.push(url);

        // Aggiungi l'immagine alla lista visuale
        var imageList = document.getElementById("imageList");
        var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        imgElement.src = url;
        imgElement.style.width = "100px"; // Puoi modificare o rimuovere questa riga se preferisci
        imgElement.style.marginRight = "10px"; // Puoi modificare o rimuovere questa riga se preferisci
        imageList.appendChild(imgElement);

        // Resetta l'input per permettere l'aggiunta di nuove immagini
        imageInput.value = "";
    }
}

// Funzione per creare la card con tutte le immagini e i dati
function addImage() {
    var marca = document.getElementById("marca").value;
    var modello = document.getElementById("modello").value;
    var prezzo = document.getElementById("prezzo").value;
    var km = document.getElementById("km").value;
    var alimentazione = document.getElementById("alimentazione").value;
    var cambio = document.getElementById("cambio").value;

    // Creiamo un oggetto per rappresentare la nuova auto
    var newCar = {
        marca: marca,
        modello: modello,
        prezzo: prezzo,
        km: km,
        alimentazione: alimentazione,
        cambio: cambio,
        images: imageUrls
    };

    // Invia i dati al backend per salvarli
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cars', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newCar)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(car => {
        // Visualizziamo l'auto appena creata
        displayCar(car);

        // Resetta i campi del form e la lista delle immagini
        imageUrls = [];
        document.getElementById("imageList").innerHTML = "";
        resetForm();
    });
}

// Funzione per visualizzare una card di un'auto
function displayCar(car) {
    // Genera un ID univoco per il carousel
    var carouselId = 'carouselExample' + carouselIdCounter++;

    var cardTemplate = '<div class="card" style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 100px; width: 40rem;">' +
        '    <div id="' + carouselId + '" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">' +
        '        <div class="carousel-inner">';

    // Aggiungi le immagini alla card
    car.images.forEach((url, index) => {
        cardTemplate += '            <div class="carousel-item ' + (index === 0 ? 'active' : '') + '">' +
            '                <img src="' + url + '" alt="Auto Image">' + // Rimuovi le classi fisse
            '            </div>';
    });

    cardTemplate += '        </div>' +
        '        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#' + carouselId + '" data-bs-slide="prev">' +
        '            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
        '            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>' +
        '        </button>' +
        '        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#' + carouselId + '" data-bs-slide="next">' +
        '            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
        '            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>' +
        '        </button>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <div class="card-body">' +
        '      <h5 class="card-title">' + car.marca + ' ' + car.modello + '</h5>' +
        '      <p class="card-text">Prezzo: ' + car.prezzo + ' €</p>' +
        '      <p class="card-text">Km: ' + car.km + '</p>' +
        '      <p class="card-text">Alimentazione: ' + car.alimentazione + '</p>' +
        '      <p class="card-text">Cambio: ' + car.cambio + '</p>' +
        '      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateImage()">Aggiorna Auto</button>' +
        '      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteImage()">Elimina Auto</button>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '</div>';

    document.getElementById("addBlog").insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", cardTemplate);

    // Re-inizializza il carousel
    var myCarousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(document.getElementById(carouselId), {
        interval: false
    });
}

// Funzione per resettare i campi del form
function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("marca").value = "";
    document.getElementById("modello").value = "";
    document.getElementById("prezzo").value = "";
    document.getElementById("km").value = "";
    document.getElementById("alimentazione").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("cambio").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("image").value = "";
}

function UpdateImage() {
    // Funzionalità per aggiornare i dettagli dell'auto
    alert('Funzione di aggiornamento non implementata.');
}

function deleteImage() {
    // Funzionalità per eliminare la card dell'auto
    alert('Funzione di eliminazione non implementata.');
}



First of all, your question mentions Java, which is NOT the same as Javascript. How is your code not working as expected?

Not exactly related to your questions, but "it is hidden on a page" means, that it's available for anyone who can use browsers' DevTools. If you've some content providing users being signed in, it shouldn't be included in the page at all, if a visitor hasn't signed in.

@Teemu so how i can hide it at 100%?

Like said, don't include it on the page, that's the only 100% way.

Is the form data we're seeing in the table stored persistently or only via local storage? At first glance it seems you code is sending a JSOn to an API end point. This JSON data could be stored as a .json file via php and retrieved in the frontend to display the product card layout.

Guys I'm very ignorant about backend, I don't know how to make a database etc. I saw that you can create a database on siteground and therefore ok, but the site is hosted on register.it and there is no possibility of creating a database from the host,
how can I do? In practice what I want to do is create a form that, once filled in, saves that data and puts it on the site in the form of a post, a bit as if it were the input field of a forum (but with various fields and the possibility of image upload)
